# Mapping additional arguments to purrr

Tags: r, lm, purrr

I'm trying to map the function below to a nested dataframe using purrr. I've tried to look at the docs but just can't wrap my head around a way to pass additional arguments to the function.

Sample data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
nested<-iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest()
```

Function to implement:

```
lm_mod<-function(df,xname,yname){
 xname<-deparse(substitute(xname))
 yname<-deparse(substitute(yname))
 f1<-as.formula(paste(yname,"~",xname))
 do.call(lm,list(data=quote(df),f1))
  }
```

One of several attempts:

```
map(nested$data,lm_mod(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length))
```

Error:

> Error in stats::model.frame(formula = df, data = ~Petal.Length, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
>     object 'Sepal.Length' not found

It appears that my formula is interpreted as the data. How can I best implement this?

Comment: When calling lm() the formula should come first. Right now in you do.call you have the formula as the second item in your list. Just switch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it: The problem was with my function definition that I later edited to explicitly state the data argument in the `lm` call  and thanks to @MrFlick too for pointing that out:

```
lm_mod<-function(df,xname,yname){
 xname<-deparse(substitute(xname))
 yname<-deparse(substitute(yname))
 f1<-as.formula(paste(yname,"~",xname))
 do.call(lm,list(data=quote(df),f1))
  }

map(nested$data,lm_mod,Sepal.Length,Petal.Length)
```